# Как отобразить элемент ввода над клавиатурой, если она была вызвана на элементе input в WebView

Tags: android, unity3d, android-webview, android-softkeyboard

Использую [UniWebView](https://uniwebview.com/) для отображения своего приложения/сайта.

При клике на инпут клава перекрывает поле для ввода. Если бы это был нативный `EditText`, то клава бы сдвинула контент вверх и всё было бы нормально.

1. `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` не помогает.
2. `TouchScreenKeyboard.hideInput = false` [клавиатуры](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileKeyboard.html), чтоб хоть дефолтное поле было, тоже не работает.

Как мне сделать видимым поле ввода?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` тоже не помогает? А activity `fullscreen`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб в фулскрине как раз adjustResize вообще не работает. Юнити внутри вообще много всякой гадости делает, ничего из того, что советуют для нативных Android приложение, не помогло.

Comment: Т.е. без фулскрина работает? И проблема именно в том чтобы в фулскрине заставить работать? Если что - я точно не знаю ответа, просто мне интересно как можно локализовать проблему и сделать вопрос более понятным)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб в юнити без фулскрина нельзя в принципе)

Comment: Жесть какая))) А возможность вызвать ява код, убирающий этот флаг, есть?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вызывал, но там всё равно проблема с имерсив режимом. Статус бар вроде есть, а вьюха рисуется под ним. В общем, очень всё мутно.

Comment: А с клавой это помогло? Если да, то можно флагами ещё запретить рисовать под статус баром и навбаром.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб решил костыльно модификацией страницы :D

Comment: Вот по этому надо всё нативно писать) Круто, что получилось - наверняка вопрос популярный будет)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб надеюсь, кому-нить кроме меня поможет )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Нужно определить, открылась/закрылась ли клавиатура. В [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/883708/15479) я это решил. Оттуда же высоту клавиатуры получаю:

   ```
   private void InitKeyboardListener() {
       using (AndroidJavaClass unityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer")) {
           AndroidJavaObject activityRootView = unityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity").Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getWindow").Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getDecorView").Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getRootView");
           AndroidJavaObject observer = activityRootView.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getViewTreeObserver");

           observer.Call("addOnGlobalLayoutListener", new OnGlobalLayoutListener(() => {
               AndroidJavaClass unityClass2 = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
               var activity = unityClass2.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

               AndroidJavaObject rect = new AndroidJavaObject("android.graphics.Rect");
               AndroidJavaObject view = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getWindow").Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getDecorView").Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getRootView");
               view.Call("getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame", rect);

               AndroidJavaObject display = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getWindowManager").Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getDefaultDisplay");
               AndroidJavaObject size = new AndroidJavaObject("android.graphics.Point");
               display.Call("getSize", size);
               int screenHeight = size.Get<int>("y");

               // высота клавы
               int heightDiff = view.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getRootView").Call<int>("getHeight") - (rect.Get<int>("bottom") - rect.Get<int>("top"));

               if (heightDiff > screenHeight / 3) {
                    // клава открылась
               }
               else {
                    // клава закрылась
                    // но есть проблема, если клавиатура откреплена от футера
                    // тогда логика тоже сюда пойдёт
               }
           }));
       }
   }
   ```
2. Передаю эту высоту в `WebView`, вызываю свою js функцию:

   ```
   public static void SetKeyboardOffset(int height) { 
       string code = string.Format("window.globalReactFunctions.apiSetKeyboardOffset('{0}')", height);
             m_WebView.EvaluateJavaScript(code, (payload) => {
       });
   }
   ```
3. В коде блока страницы `padding` меняю:

   ```
   <div style={{paddingBottom: this.props.keyboardOffset/window.devicePixelRatio + "px"}}>
   ```

В итоге костыль на костыле, но вроде всё работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]