# Узнать, открыта ли клавиатура при клике на input в WebView в Unity3d под Android

Tags: android, unity3d, android-webview, android-softkeyboard

`TouchScreenKeyboard.visible` [клавиатуры](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileKeyboard.html) всегда равен `false`, если клавиатура открылась по клику на `input` в `WebView`.

Как без использования нативных плагинов определить, когда клавиатура открылась/закрылась?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделал очень костыльно - использую обсервер на изменение слоя:

```
private void InitKeyboardListener() {
    using (AndroidJavaClass unityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer")) {
        AndroidJavaObject activityRootView = unityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity").Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getWindow").Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getDecorView").Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getRootView");
        AndroidJavaObject observer = activityRootView.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getViewTreeObserver");

        observer.Call("addOnGlobalLayoutListener", new OnGlobalLayoutListener(() => {
            AndroidJavaClass unityClass2 = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
            var activity = unityClass2.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

            AndroidJavaObject rect = new AndroidJavaObject("android.graphics.Rect");
            AndroidJavaObject view = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getWindow").Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getDecorView").Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getRootView");
            view.Call("getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame", rect);

            AndroidJavaObject display = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getWindowManager").Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getDefaultDisplay");
            AndroidJavaObject size = new AndroidJavaObject("android.graphics.Point");
            display.Call("getSize", size);
            int screenHeight = size.Get<int>("y");

            int heightDiff = view.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getRootView").Call<int>("getHeight") - (rect.Get<int>("bottom") - rect.Get<int>("top"));

            if (heightDiff > screenHeight / 3) {
                 // клава открылась
            }
            else {
                 // клава закрылась
                 // но есть проблема, если клавиатура откреплена от футера
                 // тогда логика тоже сюда пойдёт
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: у вас хорошие ответы,  хотя они не по моей специализации, читаю всегда с интересом. Поздравляю с круглой цифрой!

Comment: @Alexandr_TT спасибо ^_^